# ASP.NET Web Site Administration Tool Security tab shows error 1802

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, access-denied

I'm following this walkthrough:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/879kf95c(VS.80).aspx

In a machine running vista ultimate, I have installed:

- IIS
- SQL Server Express 2005
- Visual Studio 2005

I created a new website and I can access it ok via http://127.0.0.1
but I want to learn to create a login and have user memberships.

When I get to the tutorial step:

> To create a membership user
>
> 1. On the Website menu, click ASP.NET Configuration.
> 2. Select the Security tab, ...

I get this error:

> There is a problem with your selected
>   data store. This can be caused by an
>   invalid server name or credentials, or
>   by insufficient permission. It can
>   also be caused by the role manager
>   feature not being enabled. Click the
>   button below to be redirected to a
>   page where you can choose a new data
>   store.
>
> The following message may help in
>   diagnosing the problem: An error
>   occurred during the execution of the
>   SQL file 'InstallCommon.sql'. The SQL
>   error number is 1802 and the
>   SqlException message is: CREATE
>   DATABASE failed. Some file names
>   listed could not be created. Check
>   related errors. CREATE FILE
>   encountered operating system error
>   5(Access is denied.) while attempting
>   to open or create the physical file
>   'C:\INETPUB\WWWROOT\MEMBERSHIP\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB_TMP.MDF'.
>   Creating the
>   ASPNETDB_9b571c52c35b447ab7947888fa99b6b8
>   database...

Why? I'm running visual studio as administrator. (right-click "run as administrator" option).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here is what fixed it:

1)

- went to control panel -> programs and features -> Turn windows features on or off.
- checked "windows authentication" here:

[image: screencap]

2)

- I went to control panel -> administrative tools -> Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager
- Selected my webapp in the tree to the left.
- Selected "authentication" under IIS
- Enabled "windows authentication"

Answer (score 0):

maybe c:\inetpub\wwwroot\membership\app_data\ is read-only

Comment: I checked the folder permissions, there were several accounts (for example "Network System") with full control. Maybe some account was missing? But that had nothing to do in the end.

Answer (score 0):

This answer and other research helped me get this working. I have summarized the steps in detail here http://www.yart.com.au/Resources/Programming/ASP-NET-Security-Doesnt-Work.aspx